# Check whether character exists in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive function that checks whether a certain character exists in a list(the list can contain sublists).

So far I've come up with this but it doesn't seem to be working.
What am I doing wrong?

```
    def exists(str, seq):
        if not seq:
            return 0
        elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
            return exists(seq[0]) + exists(seq[1:])
        elif str == seq[0]:
            return True
        else:
            return exists(seq[1:])
```

If I try

```
    print(exists("c", [a,[b,c],d]))
```

I get name "a" is not defined

Comment: So, are you getting an error message, or...?

Comment: it should not even run, your `exists` requires 2 arguments, and you pass only one in recurssion (where is `str`?)

Comment: Hint: do you know what are doing the quotes around `c` in `exists("c", [a,[b,c],d])`?

Comment: You probably mean `["a", ["b", "c"], "d"]` for the second argument.

Answer (score 2):

```
def exists(str, seq):
```

You should not use the built-in type `str` as the name of a variable.

```
        return 0
```

For binary functions you should return `False`, not 0.

```
        return exists(seq[0]) + exists(seq[1:])
```

Calls to `exist` must have two arguments, not one. And you should use `or`, not `+`.

```
        return exists(seq[1:])
```

Calls to `exist` must have two arguments, not one.

```
print(exists("c", [a,[b,c],d]))
```

`[a,[b,c],d]` Means "a nested list containing the variables named a, b, c, and d". If you don't have variables with those names, this will crash with a NameError. Perhaps you meant to use string literals.

```
def exists(s, seq):
    if not seq:
        return False
    elif isinstance(seq[0], list):
        return exists(s, seq[0]) or exists(s, seq[1:])
    elif s == seq[0]:
        return True
    else:
        return exists(s, seq[1:])

print(exists("c", ["a",["b","c"],"d"]))
```

Answer (score 2):

> "I get name "a" is not defined".

That is because it is not defined, assuming this is your full code. The same applies to `b`, `c` and `d`.

You need to either define those variables beforehand (1.) with some string objects, or write the letters as string literals themselves (2.):

1. `a, b, c, d = "my_string1", "my_string2", "my_string3", "my_string4"`
2. `print(exists('c', ['a', ['b', 'c'], 'd']))`

Apart from that, you define your function as `def exists(str, seq):`, but you invoke it as `exists(seq[0])` which means you are missing a parameter.

Then you are trying to add boolean values, which might work, but I am not sure if it is what you want to achieve: `return exists(seq[0]) + exists(seq[1:])`. If converted to a boolean, `2` will also be `True`. But it will also be `True` if one of the statements is `0`. To check whether both or none are `True`, you should multiply the values. Also, try to use the same return type for every return case.

You are also using the first character (or item) of your seq, while you actually wanted to use the first character of the string `str`. Careful! `str`is a type class, do NOT use it as a variable name.